# how do i get an element of a spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a dataframe like below:

```
df :
+-----------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| a                     | b                       | c                   |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 1                     | 1                       | 0.2                 |
| 1                     | 2                       | 0.3                 |
| 1                     | 3                       | 0.4                 |
| 1                     | 4                       | 0.5                 |
| 1                     | 5                       | 0.2                 |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

How do I get value of c where a = 1 and b =2?

Comment: please research on dataframe .filter() and .where() methods. If you need it as a variable use .collect(). If you need something else, post what you have tried and a sample output

Answer (score 0):

```
val resDF = df.filter(col("a").equalTo(1)).filter(col("b").equalTo(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`val col_c = df.filter(col("a").equalTo(1).and(col("b").equalTo(2))).select("c")`